# “Without entering the parameter, the system will not send data information to the user's email - this sounds weird?

Tags: prepositions

I want to say, "If the user does not enter the parameter, the system will not send data information to the user's email."

But I want to use the word "without". I think Example 3 conveys my original meaning better because Example 1 and 2 sound like the system do the entering itself.

I wonder whether when a preposition is used, its default implied subject is the same as the subject of the main clause.

**Example 1:**

> Without entering the parameter, the system will not send data information to the user's email.

**Example 2:**

> The system will not send data information to the user's email without entering the parameter.

**Example 3:**

> Without the user entering the parameter, the system will not send data information to the user's email.

Comment: Examples 1 and 2 contain an error called a [**dangling participle**](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/dangling-participle).  The error is exactly what you mentioned: "when a preposition is used, its default implied subject is the same as the subject of the main clause".  When you say "Without entering the information, the system will..." what you're saying is that the *system* isn't entering the information!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Just want to make sure: "when a preposition is used, its default implied subject is the same as the subject of the main clause" is not a universal rule, right? because I just thought of exceptions, "About swimming in the sea, experts suggest wearing life jackets" and "For dressing formally, a blazer is a good choice." The implied subjects of the preposition phrases are not experts and not a blazer.

Comment: I think those exceptions are not really exceptions.  If you re-order them as "experts suggest wearing life jackets for swimming in the sea" and "a blazer is a good choice for dressing formally", they are correct, whereas "the system will not send data information to the user's email without entering the parameter" is still wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Would it help if you rewrote it?:

The user needs to enter the parameter (in order) to receive data (information) by email from the system.

Comment: Or, "Without **the user** entering the parameter, the system will not send ... to the user's email"? The "..." should probably be either "data" or "information" instead of "data information," unless the context is information *about* data.